# How to download an image with a "data:image"-type source with Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I've attempted to do this the normal way, where I select the image by ID and then get the contents of the `src` attribute like so:

```
img = wd.find_element_by_id('image')
src = img.get_attribute('src')
urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "local_image.png")
```

However, the third line of this snippet fails as it expects `a string or bytes-like object`

Full traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "image.py", line 36, in <module>
    urllib.request.urlretrieve(src, "image.png")
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\request.py", line 245, in urlretrieve
    url_type, path = _splittype(url)
  File "C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\urllib\parse.py", line 1008, in _splittype
    match = _typeprog.match(url)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

Does anyone have any pointers?

Comment: Could you show us the url of the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it done with `requests` and `shutil` modules:

```
import shutil
import requests
img = wd.find_elements_by_tag_name('img')
src = img.get_attribute('src')
print(src)
url = 'yoururl/'+ src['my_image']
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
with open('my_pic.png', 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response.raw, out_file
```

Comment: It refers to the website

Comment: The src variable shows up as a "NoneType". In other words, it's an empty variable.

Comment: I've updated my answer to get all items with `<img>`, so you could see if at all there are any images

Comment: `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get_attribute'`. It looks like it can't find the image on the page for some reason?